# Reusing existing buffer in vim

Tags: vim, centos7

I am trying to learn how to write vim-plugin and thought easiest way to write a compilation function by my own to get something started with vim-plugin and ended up following:

```
function! PreprocessingCode(commands)
    " Get the bytecode.
    try
        let bytecode = system(a:commands . " -E -o " . bufname("%") . " 2>&1")
    catch
        echo v:exception
    endtry

    " Check that buffer already exist
    if bufwinnr('__Bytecode__') > 0
       "Code to replace the buffer.
       setlocal filetype=objectcode
       setlocal buftype=nofile
       call append(0, split(bytecode, '\v\n'))
    else
        " Open a new split and set it up.
        vsplit __Bytecode__
        normal! ggdG
        setlocal filetype=objectcode
        setlocal buftype=nofile

        " Insert the bytecode.
        call append(0, split(bytecode, '\v\n'))
     endif
endfunction

nnoremap <buffer> <localleader>b :call PreprocessingCode("g++")<cr>
```

The main issue is I want to use the `__Bytecode__` buffer. So that if a buffer is already opened then function should reuse the existing buffer so that if I press b multiple time it should not open multiple stack of windows via vsplit.

Struck here. Don't know how to achieve the desired result? 
Any thoughts guys? 
Thanks.

Comment: I'm short on time to answer properly, it seems you're looking for a function similar to my [`lh#buffer#jump()`](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/autoload/lh/buffer.vim#L106). And I'm quite sure to have already answered this question a few times. Was it on SO? I cannot tell.

Comment: I tried a way around though not prefered as:   `if bufwinnr('`__Bytecode__`') > 0 ;   wincmd h;
       normal! ggdG;  setlocal filetype=objectcode;
       setlocal buftype=nofile;
       call append(0, split(bytecode, '\v\n'));`

Comment: Is there any better way to override buffer with new content?

Comment: You don't need to do jump to the window by hand. You can go directly with the number you get back from `bufwinnr()`. e.g. `let wnnr = bufwinnr('__Bytecode__') | if winnr > 0 | execute wnnr . "windcmd w" | else | vsplit __Bytecode__ | endif`

Comment: Probably a bit more robust if you have a newer version of Vim. e.g. `call win_gotoid(get(win_findbuf(bufnr('__Bytecode__)), 0, -1))`